# BackBone collection takes array of models as a single model?

Tags: backbone.js, collections, model, models

In this below code

```
 var productcollection = new Products([this.$results]);
 alert(productcollection.length);
```

here this.$results holds a string more like this

```
{"ProdID":"98","ProdName":"product1","ProdPic":"null","ProdGist":"null","ProdDesc":"null","ProdCat":"","ProdTech":"","LastModified":""},{"ProdID":"928","ProdName":"product21","ProdPic":"null","ProdGist":"null","ProdDesc":"null","ProdCat":"","ProdTech":"","LastModified":""}
```

But the length of the collection is returned as "1" . what correction should i make to the  models data that i am giving to the collection . So that it returns "2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really have a string in this.$results try this:

```
var array = JSON.parse('['+this.$results+']');
var productcollection = new Products( array );
```

Your code was creating an Array containing one large string, like:

```
new Products( ["text"] );
```

Comment: that worked . ! But eager to learn  the problem behind my code??? Why was it considered as a single entity than a array of models?

Comment: edited, does this help you to understand what happened in your code?

Comment: yeah .! you are right . Well explained 
Is there a way to Pick the models and read their attribute values as we are not naming the models here?

Comment: productcollection.at(0) gives you the first model and so on. productcollection.at(0).get("attribute-name") gives your an attribute of the first model in the collection